# how to reset vscode teminal UI to default

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image]

Reset vscode teminal UI to default

[image]

Comment: It is the new default, after the last update.

Answer (score 0):

In the settings, go to

> Terminal.Integrated.Tabs

and remove the checkmark.

[image: Terminal Tabs Disabled]